# Socket.io 404 Error on Angular 2 App

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, socket.io

I am building an Angular 2 app, and so far most things have gone according to plan. However, today when I went to boot up my app, I get an error message in the browser console saying:

```
Error: Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/node_modules//socket.io-client/socket.io.js(…)
```

What's bizarre to me is that a version of the app I have from a couple of days ago boots up with no problem, and none of the relevant parts of the app are any different. So... where to look to resolve this issue? Also, to clarify, no errors arise in the terminal when I type "npm start", instead I just get the "Loading..." text hanging in the browser, and when I look at the console, that's when I see the error I included above.

Here's my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "abc",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "typings": "typings",
    "docs": "typedoc --experimentalDecorators --out docs/ app/ --target 'es5' -module 'system' --ignoreCompilerErrors",
    "clean": "del /q dist",
    "browserify": "^13.0.1",
    "uglifyjs": "^2.4.10",
    "minify": "uglifyjs dist/main.min.js --screw-ie8 --compress --mangle --output dist/main.min.js",
    "build": "npm run clean && tsc",
    "build_prod": "npm run build && browserify -s main dist/main.js > dist/main.min.js && npm run minify"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^2.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^2.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-alpha.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^3.0.0",
    "@angular2-material/button": "^2.0.0-alpha.8-2",
    "@angular2-material/core": "^2.0.0-alpha.8-2",
    "@angular2-material/input": "^2.0.0-alpha.8-2",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.1.15",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "socket.io-client": "^1.4.8",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "typings": "^1.5.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.23"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.32",
    "browserify": "^13.0.1",
    "concurrently": "^2.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.5.2",
    "karma": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "typescript": "^2.0.2",
    "typings": "^1.5.0",
    "uglifyjs": "^2.4.10"
  }
}
```

Comment: Is your application server running at port 3000?

Comment: Yes. It is running at port 3000. And for the app that is working, it's running on port 3002.

Comment: I've switched out which port the two versions of the app load on, and it doesn't make any difference. The version from a few days ago works, and the one from today doesn't. Identical files pertaining to socket.io.